# How do I set two different login paths for authorization challenge? (ASP.NET Core Razor Pages)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

So this is how I set login path which redirects to login page for authorization challenge, right?

```
builder.Services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";

});
```

But what if I have two login pages - one for admin and one for regular users? How do I register two different login pages for two different parts of the web?

Comment: Why though? Are you using 2 different authentication services? This is something usually Roles or Claims handle.

Comment: You could define 2 authorization policies, with 2 authentication schemes. But do you really need it?

Answer (score 3):

You can overwrite the OnRedirectToLogin event on the options :

```
builder.services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, options =>
{
     options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
     options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
     {
          if (IsAdminContext(context))
          {
             var redirectPath = new Uri(context.RedirectUri);
             context.Response.Redirect("/Account/AdminLogin" + redirectPath.Query);
          }
          else
          {
             context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
          }
           return Task.CompletedTask;
      };
 });
```

And Create  Helper Method Like This :

```
 private static bool IsAdminContext(RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions> context)
 {
    return context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/admin");
 }
```

Comment: Well done! I have a two-step login, and it helped me to redirect to the second step